# How do I find out which libraries a Java program uses on start-up?

Tags: java, stack-trace, backtrace

Trying to debug a Java based program that works on one machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and not the other one (same OS).  Is there a way that I can find out what programs/libraries are called upon starting this Java program?  In other words, I think I am missing a file/library on one machine that is causes the Java program to crash. Is this called a backtrace?

Comment: What happens when you run the program on the machine that fails?

Comment: Some kind of error message would be coming out from the run of this application if it couldn't load.  That'd be a *stacktrace*, which you could then use to look up the specific error.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError

Comment: 14/03/2017 09:59:43 EDT ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.clcbio.log.Core.UI: Encountered an unexpected error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.biobam.blast2go.api.user.UserInfo.<init>(Lcom/biobam/blast2go/api/user/UserInfo$TYPE;ILjava/lang/String;)V
 at com.blast2go.util.B2GPluginInitializer.init(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at com.clcbio.api.free.workbench.PluginInitializer.register(PluginInitializer.java:6) ~[api-workbench.jar:na]
 at

Answer (score 1):

You have two versions of the same jar library, or multiple libraries.

For example, you have `bla‌​st2go.old.jar` version and `bla‌​st2go.new.jar` version.

Class `B2GPluginInitializer` from a `bla‌​st2go.new.jar` creates object of `UserInfo` calling its constructor.

But, unfortunately, class loader loads `UserInfo` from `bla‌​st2go.old.jar`, not from `bla‌​st2go.new.jar`, as it should.
So, to check path to the incorrect library you can use the code below.

You can do this check somewhere in the code before exception

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource("com/biobam/blast2go/api/user/UserInfo.class");
System.out.println(url);
```

The second step is check the class `B2GPluginInitializer` from which a constructor is called.

Comment: I did not understand your response, can you explain in more detail?  And can you explain how I would do this?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.